# General purpose Tuple in Hadoop

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce, apache-pig

I'm new to Hadoop, so please do not judge strictly my seemingly simple question.

The short version: **What tuple data type can I use in Hadoop, to store 2 longs as a single value is a sequence file?** 
Moreover, I want to be able to read and process this file with *Apache Pig* like `A = LOAD '/my/file' AS (a:long, (b:long, c:long))` and with *Scala & Spark* like `val a = sc.sequenceFile[LongWritable, DesiredTuple]("/my/file", 1)`.

The full story:

I'm writing a Hadoop Job in Java, and I need to output a sequence file, which contains 3 long values at each line. I use first value a a key and group two other values together as a value in my Reducer.

I tried several variants:
Using `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.join.TupleWritable`

```
public class MyReducer extends Reducer<...> {
    public void reduce(Context context){
        long a,b,c;
        // ...
        context.write(a, new TupleWritable(
                new LongWritable[]{new LongWritable(b), new LongWritable(c)}));
    }
}
```

But the javadoc of TupleWritable class says " * This is *not* a general-purpose tuple type." It seems to be ok for first attempt, but I can't get back my Tuples. Look as a simple script in Apace Pig:

```
A = LOAD '/my/file' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.SequenceFileLoader() 
        AS (a:long, (b:long, t:long));
DUMP A;
```

I got Something like this:

```
(2220,)
(5640,)
(6240,)
...
```

**So what is the Apache Pig way of reading Hadoop's TupleWritable from a sequence file?**

Furthermore, I tried to change sequence format to text format: `job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);`

This time I just looked in one of outputed files:

```
> hdfs dfs -cat /my/file/part-r-00000 | head
2220    [,]
5640    [,]
6240    [,]
...
```

So is the next question: **Why there is nothing in my TupleWritable value?**

After that, I tried `org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.EntityEntityWritable`.
For a sequence file I got the same result as before:

```
grunt> A = LOAD '/my/file' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.SequenceFileLoader() AS (a:long, (b:long, c:long));
(2220,)
(5640,)
(6240,)
...
```

For a text file I got the desired result:

```
2220    2   15
5640    1   9
6240    0   1
...
```

And next question is: **How to read such tuples (EntityEntityWritable) and may be other custom objects back from Hadoop-written sequence file?**

Comment: I think it will be helpful if your create own Serializable type to hold these multiple values. After that you would need to write your own Pig Loader class that extends org.apache.pig.FileInputLoadFunc.